# Method: Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, return, xna-4.0

Ok so while working on an XNA 4.0 game I'm developing I came across this problem with one of my methods which is getting the error 'not all code paths return a value' and well this has been driving me insane for the past couple hours.

```
 private Rectangle HandleCollision(Rectangle bounds, TileCollision collision, Rectangle tileBounds)
    {
        Vector2 depth = RectangleExtensions.GetIntersectionDepth(bounds, tileBounds);
        if (depth != Vector2.Zero)
        {
            float absDepthX = Math.Abs(depth.X);
            float absDepthY = Math.Abs(depth.Y);

            // Resolve the collision along the shallow axis.  
            if (absDepthY < absDepthX || collision == TileCollision.Platform)
            {
                // If we crossed the top of a tile, we are on the ground.
                // also ladder
                if (previousBottom <= tileBounds.Top)
                {
                    if (collision == TileCollision.Ladder)
                    {
                        if (!isClimbing && !isJumping)
                        {
                            //walking over a ladder
                            isOnGround = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isOnGround = true;
                        isClimbing = false;
                        isJumping = false;
                    }
                }


                // Ignore platforms, unless we are on the ground.  
                if (collision == TileCollision.Impassable || IsOnGround)
                {
                    // Resolve the collision along the Y axis.  
                    Position = new Vector2(Position.X, Position.Y + depth.Y);

                    // Perform further collisions with the new bounds.  
                    bounds = BoundingRectangle;
                }
            }
            else if (collision == TileCollision.Impassable) // Ignore platforms.  
            {
                // Resolve the collision along the X axis.  
                Position = new Vector2(Position.X + depth.X, Position.Y);

                // Perform further collisions with the new bounds.  
                bounds = BoundingRectangle;
            }

            else if (collision == TileCollision.Ladder && !isClimbing)
            {
                //stops colliding with ladder if player walks past or drops off ladder
                Position = new Vector2(Position.X, Position.Y);

                //perform collisions with new bounds
                bounds = BoundingRectangle;
            }
            return bounds;
        }
    }
```

Any help understanding this error would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does it return if `depth == Vector2.Zero`?

Comment: You should thing about making bounds an `out` parameter.

Comment: Your return statement is inside an if block - any code which will not enter that if block will not return anything but your method requires to return a Rectangle type. Having the return statement outside the if block should resolve the issue.

Comment: return bounds; is inside your main if statement. is there a default value you can return? either way, you need to return something outside of your if statement, in case it never makes it to the return bounds; line. maybe create bound before the if, set it to null, and return after the if statement.

Comment: Cheers guys, sorry for that I feel really stupid now.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is here.

```
if (depth != Vector2.Zero)
```

if this evaluates to false, nothing gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `return bounds;` statement outside the `if` statement. If that `if` statement resolves to false then the return is never hit.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked, cant believe it was that simple I feel like a complete idiot now..

Answer (score 0):

If depth is equal to Vector2.Zero you don't return anything. Hence, not all code paths return a value.

Answer (score 0):

What if your `depth != Vector2.Zero` return `false` in

```
if ( depth != Vector2.Zero )
```

condition?

Your method doesn't return anything at this point. You must return value also outside of this loop.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement is nested inside of your conditional. So if (depth == Vector2.Zero) the method will not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

it's because if you first `IF` would return `false` then as the error says `Not all code paths return a value`. you should consider adding a return value or may be an exception for that case

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your final return value outside of your if:

```
private Rectangle HandleCollision(Rectangle bounds, TileCollision collision, Rectangle tileBounds)
{
  if(depth != Vector2.Zero)
  {

  }
  return bounds;
}
```

you have it like this:

```
private Rectangle HandleCollision(Rectangle bounds, TileCollision collision, Rectangle tileBounds)
{
  if(depth != Vector2.Zero)
  {
     return bounds;
  }
}
```

What this means, is if `depth == Vector2.Zero` nothing gets returned, so you get the error that you are seeing.